# Python creating dictionaries in loop

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Can anyone please help me in creating dictionary in loop.

I want my dictionary to be

```
Input
d={'a':'a1,a2,a3,.....,a10', 'b':'b1,b2,b3,....,b10'}

print(d) 
{'a': 'a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10', 'b': 'b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10'}
```

Reason for asking this I have huge amount of dictionaries to make. Trying to make it a smart way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
d = dict()
keys = ['a','b']
for i in keys:
  d[i] = [f"{i}{j}" for j in range(1,11)]
```

Note that if you want a single string, just write this inside the loop:

```
d[i] = ','.join[f"{i}{j}" for j in range(1,11)]
```

Comment: It can be a one liner using dict-comprehension: `{k: ','.join[f"{k}{j}" for j in range(1,11)] for k in keys}`